# Validar la existencia de una URI antes de lanzar el intent en Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Normalmente recurro al `try-catch` para detectar si el proceso de lanzar un Intent ha tenido éxito o no.

Por ejemplo para abrir el panel de equalizador de la configuración del sistema, hay modelos que lo tienen y de otros el fabricante lo ha quitado

```
Intent i = new Intent(AudioEffect.ACTION_DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL);
try {
    startActivity(i);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Con `Try-Catch` lo detecto pero ¿me pregunto si hay una forma previa para saber si está disponible?

O la manera más optima, que no gaste tantos recursos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez puedas usar el método [`resolveActivityInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivityInfo(android.content.pm.PackageManager,%20int)):

```
boolean activityExiste = intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null;
```

Según la **[documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html)** de Android:

> Si no hay apps en el dispositivo que puedan recibir la intent
>   implícita, tu app fallará cuando llame a `startActivity()`. Para
>   verificar primero que exista una app para recibir la intent, llama a
>   `resolveActivity()` en tu objeto Intent. Si el resultado no es null,
>   hay al menos una app que puede administrar la intent y será seguro
>   llamar a `startActivity()`. Si el resultado es null, no debes usar la
>   intent y, si es posible, debes inhabilitar la función que la invoca.